# Is there a way to see all instance methods from within the rails controller/debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

Something like this

```
c = Client.find(1)
c.instance_methods
```

Similar to what pry does with `ls` I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c.methods` unless you're looking for something different?

Comment: thats it, just never ran into it before.

Comment: @calebB Yup, I use it all the time because I can't ever remember the names of things ;)